# How to retrieve notifications from my application in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a multiple user logged-in each one can add an alert in his location. This alert willl be stocked in Firebase database.

**Problem**

The problem is what should I do to make users get notification if there is an alert declared in his area.

[image: alerts Firebase node]

[image: users Firebase node]

Comment: Since you are using Firebase, the best thing you can do is to use GeoFire api, you can register to listen on a certain radius and everytime something enters or leaves the area you can notify the users. Unfortunately I don't have the time to write an example or full answer thats why I am writing a comment instead. You can start by reading this blog post by the firebase team. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/08/geofire-goes-mobile.html

Comment: My problem is how to notify the users.I'm getting all the alerts in the area but I can't push the notification

Comment: I see, well it depends whether you want to show the alerts only when the app is in the foreground, or the background or both. For when the  app is in the foreground you can use nsusernotification or even subclass an open source popup library, I like CNPPopupController. For when the app is in the background or even worst the app quit then that is another story. I haven't worked on that but I would assume you need some sort of server/service listening to the changes on your database so that you can fireup a remote notification through FCM, sorry I am not much help, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

for IOS 9 and above use method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
  // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
  // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
  // TODO: Handle data of notification

  // Print message ID.
  print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

  // Print full message.
  print(userInfo)
}
```

In function parse and do what you need with this data.
 in IOS 10+
use import UserNotification in appdelegate header and input this method

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension HyberFirebaseMessagingDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
print(userInfo)//print user info
    }
}

extension HyberFirebaseMessagingDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
```

more details you can read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive)